# Sending a Mail on Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

hi I have a simple pipeline job that should send a mail, I configured on Manage jenkins -> Configure System with port 465 and the appropriated SMTP server , when I test the configuration by sending a e-mail  , it sends and I can see the test mail on my inbox , but from the pipeline job , it fails:

```
node {

    stage("test") {
        def message = "hello there!" 

        mail bcc: '', body: message, cc: '', from: 'jenkinsuser@mycom.com', replyTo: 'jenkinsuser@mycom.com', subject: "Develop: build generated ",     to:'grace@mycom.com'
    }

}
```

Error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:114)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2104)
Caused: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2106)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2093)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:1184)
```

Any suggestion how to fix it?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using [Email Extension](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext) plugin in scripted pipeline with no issues. Make sure you properly configured **E-mail Notification** section in **Manage Jenkins > Configure System**. Example for gmail:
[Jenkins e-mail notifications settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKIYX.png)

Plugin usage is described here: [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/). This is how I call it in Pipeline (I didn't remove variables):

```
emailext attachmentsPattern: "**/packages/rpm/splitted/${file}",
              to: "${to}",
            from: "Jenkins",
         subject: "[jenkins] ${packageFullName}: part ${part}/${files.size()}",
            body: "File received: \'${file}\'\n" +
                  "From package:  \'${packageFullName}\'\n" +
                  "Package MD5:   \'${mainMdFiveSum}\'\n" +
                  "Jenkins Build: \'${env.BUILD_URL}\'\n"
```

Comment: thank you very much for your example, I discovered that my issue was an email-ext.jpi.disabled  file on plugins directory not sure why ... I will now configure with that plugin reviewing the links that you sent me...